# angularjs form built with ng-repeat field + select option + $http.get

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have the code like this:

```
<form ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-submit="save()>
    <div ng-repeat="f in fields">
        <label for="theInput">{{ f.label }}</label>
        <select ng-model="f.value" ng-init="f.value = f.id" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in f.items"></select>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    var Mod = angular.module('myApp', []);
    function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
        var categories = [];
        $http.get(BASE_URL + 'task/listCategory').success(function(data) {
            categories = data;
        });
        $scope.fields = [
            { label: 'Category', value: 'items', items: categories }
        ];
    }
</script>
```

why angular select doesnot working like charm?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you might want to do

```
var Mod = angular.module('myApp', []);
    function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
        var categories = [];
        $http.get(BASE_URL + 'task/listCategory').success(function(data) {
            categories = data;
            $scope.fields = [{ label: 'Category', value: 'items', items: categories }];
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i have more than 1 field in forms, there's another solution?

Comment: The issue here is your `http.get`'s success function is a called asynchronously. so if you use `data` outside callback, you might not get the data. so i have put the assignment in callback. i think this technique might help you if you are having similar problems.

Comment: a way will likely work is create empty array `$scope.fields=[]` first so angular watches it...then push all the data into that empty array within success

Comment: when i fill with `$scope.fields = []`, still not working, why?